# Listing on board/integrated devices on Linux - for instance, on board keyboard

Tags: linux, devices, pci, dmidecode, lshw

Relevant to laptops only - I am trying to list all on-board (integrated) devices on laptops - such as on board keyboard, mouse touchpad, video card, etc shipped with the machine.

1. What is the best command for the job ? `dmidecode`, `lspci`, `lshw` ? Can all this data be extracted using a single tool ? For instance, I have not been able to locate any data pertaining to the on-board keyboard neither in `dmidecode` nor in `lshw`. `lspci` shows only a header line.
2. For the sake of understanding, do all such devices fall into the category of PCI devices - where each of them has its specific way to interface with the motherboard (ISA Bridge, IDE interface, different controllers, etc) ?

I am testing this on a `Lenovo EThink Pad 470`

Comment: Doesn’t `lshw` list something like “AT Translated Set 2 keyboard”? That’s the keyboard, there isn’t much information that can be obtained for an on-board keyboard.

Comment: You can try this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465764 which is now available at: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info Since also optionally posted to github, some private details are not included in upload.

Comment: @StephenKitt: as a matter of fact, my `lshw` does not show that - `dmesg` is the one who does: `[    0.995132] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3`